# @Inject public com.netflix.appinfo.ApplicationInfoManager(EurekaInstanceConfig, InstanceInfo, OptionalArgs)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss

When deploying Spring Cloud-enabled services on JBoss, there are some error messages. The specific environmental information is as follows:

1. JBoss version ：8.1
2. spring-cloud version：1.5.4
3. JDK：1.8

The specific error stack information is as follows：

```
2018-10-18 10:33:14,961 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Validator] (MSC service thread 1-7) WELD-001471: Interceptor method shutdown defined on class com.netflix.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext is not defined according to the specification. It should not throw java.lang.Exception, which is a checked exception.
2018-10-18 10:33:14,964 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Validator] (MSC service thread 1-7) WELD-001471: Interceptor method initialize defined on class com.netflix.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext is not defined according to the specification. It should not throw java.lang.Exception, which is a checked exception.
2018-10-18 10:33:14,970 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Validator] (MSC service thread 1-7) WELD-001471: Interceptor method shutdown defined on class com.netflix.eureka.aws.AwsBinderDelegate is not defined according to the specification. It should not throw java.lang.Exception, which is a checked exception.
2018-10-18 10:33:14,971 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Validator] (MSC service thread 1-7) WELD-001471: Interceptor method start defined on class com.netflix.eureka.aws.AwsBinderDelegate is not defined according to the specification. It should not throw java.lang.Exception, which is a checked exception.
2018-10-18 10:33:14,988 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."backstage-server.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."backstage-server.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type InstanceInfo with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 2 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject public com.netflix.appinfo.ApplicationInfoManager(EurekaInstanceConfig, InstanceInfo, OptionalArgs)
  at com.netflix.appinfo.ApplicationInfoManager.<init>(ApplicationInfoManager.java:0)

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:368)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:289)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:135)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:166)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:514)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
    ... 3 more

2018-10-18 10:33:15,021 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "backstage-server.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"backstage-server.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"backstage-server.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type InstanceInfo with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 2 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject public com.netflix.appinfo.ApplicationInfoManager(EurekaInstanceConfig, InstanceInfo, OptionalArgs)
  at com.netflix.appinfo.ApplicationInfoManager.<init>(ApplicationInfoManager.java:0)
"}}
2018-10-18 10:33:15,070 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "backstage-server.war" (runtime-name : "backstage-server.war")
2018-10-18 10:33:15,086 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."backstage-server.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."backstage-server.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
```

Comment: I guess these are server logs and you'll find the actual problem with your code in the application logs

Comment: If put the project into a jar package, the local boot is normal. Typing war packets to JBoss will not do.